# ui-router: Stop Nested State from Loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Let's say I have two states setup using angularjs ui-router:

```
.state('branding', {
    url: "/{branding}",
    controller: 'BrandingCtrl',
    templateUrl: '/app/Branding.html'
})
.state('branding.index', {
    url: "/index",
    controller: 'IndexCtrl',
    templateUrl: '/app/Index.html'
})
```

In my `BrandingCtrl` I'm setting up the details of the page, and also verifying the user has access to this version of the site.  If they do not have access, I can call $state.go('someotherstate') and send them away

In the case of someone going to /badbranding/index, the `BrandingCtrl` will determine the user doesn't have access and update the state.  However, the `IndexCtrl` will still be executed, even though I've changed the state in the parent controller and it should no longer be applicable.

How do I tell ui-router to cancel any execution of nested states?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just putting it as a resolve requirement to prevent the parent controller from executing as well.. I initially didn't go this route because it didn't seem like $state knew about the parameters at that point (which it doesn't), but I see that the information I needed was available in $stateParams

```
.state('branding', {
        url: "/{branding}",
        resolve: {
            HasAccess: function ($q, $stateParams) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                var branding = $stateParams.branding;

                if (/*doesn't have access*/)
                    deferred.reject('you do not have access');
                else
                    deferred.resolve();

                return deferred.promise;
            }
        },
        controller: 'BrandingCtrl',
        templateUrl: '/app/Branding.html'
    })
```